# How to reduce hieght of cell in table view iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In table view cell I have an image view and label. When user creates a location to post then I need to hide the image view and reduce the height of the cell. If the user creates an image post then I need to hide the label and show the image view and increase the height of the cell.

Here is the code I tried:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell

    guard posts.count > 0 else {
        return cell
    }

    cell.post = posts[indexPath.row]
    cell.homeVC = self
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.profileImageView.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.postImageView.tag    = indexPath.row
    cell.shareImageView.tag   = indexPath.row
    cell.nameLabel.tag        = indexPath.row
    cell.productRatingLabel.tag = indexPath.row
//        cell.postTime.tag =
//        cell.postTime.tag =
    cell.postTime.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.locationName.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell

    if cell.postImageView == nil {
        cell.postImageView.isHidden = true
        cell.locationName.isHidden = false

        return 100
    } else {
        cell.postImageView.isHidden = false
        cell.locationName.isHidden = true

        return 498
    }
}
```

[image: excepted result]

this is what i want..

Comment: How does the cell looks when you change it’s height? Are you using constraints?

Comment: Would you please share the complete code ?

Comment: @Adeel hey i have updated my question

Comment: did you tried UITableViewAutomatic Dimension as it will Automatically adjust cell Size based on your views

Comment: in your cellForRowAt indexPath, does your post object contains url string or is it nil?

Comment: calculate the Cell Height based on the content of the cell. and set the height.

Comment: @PvDev are you getting me? let me know if you have any issues

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by following,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    if let url = post.imageURL {
        return 498
    } else {
        return 100
    }
}
```

Now hide and show your imageView and locationName in your `cellForRowAt indexPath` method.

**FYI.** Code is not tested, this is just the information from which you can achieve your goal.

Let me know in case of any query.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution is

```
cell 1: cellwithImage

cell 2: cellWithoutImage

based on imageUrl is nill than display cellwithoutImagecell 
based on imgaeUrl is there than display cellwithImage
```